# Is my assumption about Time and Space Complexity of subsum algorithm correct?

Tags: ruby, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

Is the space complexity of this algorithm is O(n^3) cubic space complexity ?
As: list is an array, subs is an array + one array created with map.

Is the time complexity is O(n^4) biquadratic?
As: two times loop on list + one time map  + one time sum

```
def largest_contiguous_subsum(list)
  subs = []

  list.each_index do |idx1|
    (idx1..list.length - 1).each do |idx2|
      subs << list[idx1..idx2]
    end
  end

  subs.map(&:sum).max
end
```

I am currently trying to understand Big O concept

Comment: No, it's still quadratic: you have 2 nested loops - 1st time is `each` inside `each_index`, 2nd time is `sum` inside `map` - and their complexities should be added, not multiplied.